# How to add a global error to an Ecto Changeset

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to set an error on an Ecto.Changeset that is not specific to a field.

In my case, I have a login form and I want to set an error saying that either the email or the password is invalid. However I still want to highlight the `email` or `password` field when they are empty.

In Rails you can do that by adding an entry to `errors[:base]`. Is there an equivalent in Ecto ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Ecto.Changeset.add_error` allows you to pass any atom as the key, it doesn't have to be a field of that model. You can add the error to `:base` like this:

```
add_error(changeset, :base, "email or password is invalid")
```

and then in your template, either do:

```
<%= error_tag f, :base %>
```

or (after checking if there's an error):

```
<%= @changeset.errors[:base] %>
```

Another option for your usecase is to add the error on both `:email` and `:password`

```
changeset
|> add_error(:email, "email or password is invalid")
|> add_error(:password, "email or password is invalid")
```

Comment: I had to change it to `<%= error_tag @changeset, :base %>